# Disable loudspeaker usage for audio playback?

Tags: audio, 4.1-jelly-bean, privacy

I get my voicemail messages by e-mail (using K-9 mail), however, when I play the attached wavefile, the loudspeaker is used for the playback, so everyone around me can listen to the message, that's not what I want. How can I make sure, that the "phonespeaker" (the one used during calls) is used? I assume that K-9 mail uses a default android app for playback, so this should be about Android (Jelly Bean in my case), not about K-9 mail. Thanks :-)